# Variable that contains the actual text of the sql command/statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a script in oracle pl sql that contains number of sql commands (create,insert ...) and when some command throws an error i'm catching it with exception.
In my exception i want to show the actual text of the command, and I was wondering if there is a local variable that stores the text of the last command or if the is a way to store that text in a variable that i created.
A way in sql*plus can also help.
For example:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
VALUES
(5000, 'Apple');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  print the variable that contains tha actual text of the sql command
END;
```

Comment: Why are you catching it, and why are you using a PL/SQL block?If you just ran the statements as plain SQL in a script, at least through SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, it would show you the statement and its error together.

Comment: @omatan234, I think, your only option is to make a new variable and store the exact sql.

Comment: @AlexPoole running a script in SQL*Plus with no exceptions catching is not giving me the statement. And i need all the statements that is throwing an error in another file. there is a way to catch the exception and use a variable that stores the text of the statment ?

Comment: Only if you use dynamic SQL. Did you still have the statements inside a PL/SQL `begin`/`end`, or just a plain SQL?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have both options. can you show me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-jan/o14plsql-2045346.html

as described in the link above you should use `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK`

To print it, you could do `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);`

Comment: Doesn't work as required by OP. He needs the sql which generated the exception in the first place. error_stack doesnt return that.

Comment: ok good point. changed my answer - format_call_stack should do it

Comment: That still won't show the text of the statement that caused the error - the `insert into...` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

## You could use the SQLERRM function to as below:

```
 set serveroutput on;
 declare
 consumers_rec consumers%rowtype; 
 id_no number := 30; 

 begin
 select * into consumers_rec from consumers where CONSUMER_ID=id_no;
 dbms_output.put_line('CONSUMER_NAME' || consumers_rec.CONSUMER_NAME);
 EXCEPTION
 when no_data_found then
 dbms_output.put_line('When input is :' || id_no);
 dbms_output.put_line('ERROR MESSAGE:' || "SQLERRM" );
 dbms_output.put_line('SQLCODE:' || SQLCODE);
 end;
 /
```

You would see the output as below:

```
 anonymous block completed
 When input is :30
 ERROR MESSAGE:ORA-01403: no data found
 SQLCODE:100
```

Comment: That gives you the error message, but not the text of the SQL command that caused it, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: I guess you mean `dbms_output.put_line('ERROR MESSAGE:' || SQLERRM );`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - it is unusual to see it like that, but it works as shown; since [`SQLERRM` is a function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/sqlerrm_function.htm), it's just an unnecessarily-quoted identifier...